# Best way to model firestore data for a users items?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, nosql

I'm trying figure out the best data model for a items collection in firestore that will allow users to add items they own. I would of course show an items list and then on another page item details so I need to be able to query.

Should I create each user item as its own document with user id inside like so...

[image]

Or Since firestore charges on document reads (and each user might have hundreds of items) would it be better to create one document with user id as the document name and then put all the user items in one document like so (each item is a map type (object)....

[image]

I am not sure the best way to model this so that is both cost efficent at scale and easy to CRUD and query. Thank you! (sorry for the links, don't have enough rep to inline the images)

Comment: The only real considering for Firestore data modeling is to satisfy the queries you intend to perform.  Also consider that there is a maximum size for a document.  Other than the documented limits, Firestore scales automatically, and it won't let you perform an query that doesn't scale.  If you want to optimize for cost, that's up to you.  Only you know how your app will actually be used in production - we can't tell you that.  So you will have to estimate based on your own projections.

Comment: I guess I'm asking what the typical way to handle this would be. I'm new to noSQL. Would people typically create a new document for each item and have potentially hundreds of documents per user, or would they stuff all the users items into one document?

Comment: It depends on how their app needs to do its queries.  There is no typical, since every app has different requirements.  Determine what your queries and limitations are going to be, then design your data model taking those into account.  As of now, you haven't given any details about how your app needs to consume this data.  It might be that both are OK, or neither are OK, we just don't know.

Comment: What are the exact quries that you want to perform?

Comment: the queries would be what you would typically expect for storing anything from a user whether its tasks, items, comments.. return all items for a user, return one specific item for a user with its details, create an item for a user, delete an item for a user, select all items with this tag, etc... if watched a ton of youtube videos and read articles but I can't figure out in this case if its better to have a ton of smaller documents or one items document per user that would contain possibly hundreds of items. Im hoping someone could say 'you should do A because..and B is rediculous because.'

Comment: I realize both ways would technially work but what would be the best practice in this case concidering read times, query speed, firebase costs, etc